# Show that $ \frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}+\frac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}= 2 \csc x$

Tags: trigonometry

Verify the following identity: 
$$ \frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}+\frac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}= 2 \csc x$$

Comment: Consider what you must do in order to add the two fractions  $\frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}  +  \frac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}$ , that is, after putting them over a common denominator.  You will also want to use the variant form of the Pythagorean Identity, $1 + \tan^2 x  = \sec^2 x$.  Beyond that, you will need to do some algebra and find a common factor in the numerator and denominator to cancel.

Comment: I got this far.. (sin^2x/cos^2x)+1+(2/cosx)+(1/cos^2x)+(1/sinx)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of $\frac{(\tan x \cdot \tan x) + (1 + \sec x)(1 + \sec x)}{(1 + \sec x)(\tan x)}$ by adding fractions.  Multiply out the numerator and simplify, but leave the denominator alone for now.

Comment: It might be easier to multiply the numerator and denominator of the first fraction by $\sec x-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Method  $1:$

As
$\displaystyle\tan^2x=\sec^2x-1=(\sec x-1)(\sec x+1),\frac{\tan x}{\sec x-1}=\frac{\sec x+1}{\tan x}$

$$\implies\frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}+\frac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}=\frac{\sec x-1}{\tan x}+\frac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}=\frac{2\sec x}{\tan x}=\frac{\dfrac2{\cos x}}{\dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x}}=\frac2{\sin x}$$

Method  $2:$

$$\frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}=\frac{\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}}{1+\frac1{\cos x}}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}=\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}\text{ as } \sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$$

and 
$$\frac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}=\frac{1+\frac1{\cos x}}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}=\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$

Comment: In Method 1, representing $\tan x$ as $\frac{\sec x}{\csc x}$ would be much cleaner

Comment: @JohnJoy, Please find the edited version

Answer (score 1):

If you get stuck, you convert everything to sine and cosine values. Conceivably, use the Pythagorean theorem.

If this doesn't work, post your attempt and we can guide you from there.

Comment: I got this far.. (sin^2x/cos^2x)+1+(2/cosx)+(1/cos^2x)+(1/sinx)

Comment: @User: I suppose you should find a common denominator.

Comment: You're going to need to write out your steps -- I think something is off in this result.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}+\dfrac{1+\sec x}{\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{\tan^2 x+(1+\sec x)^2}{(1+\sec x)\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{\tan^2 x+1+\sec^2x+2\sec x}{(1+\sec x)\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{\sec^2x+\sec^2x+2\sec x}{(1+\sec x)\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{2\sec x(\sec x+1)}{(1+\sec x)\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{2\sec x}{\tan x}$$
$$\dfrac{\frac {2}{\cos x}}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}$$
$${\dfrac {2}{\cos x}}\times\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$
$$\dfrac 2 {\sin x}$$
$$2\csc x$$